# How to paginate a pandas dataframe on django based on columns

Tags: python, django, pandas, csv, pagination

I have a cvs with more than 40000 columns and I need to separate it on parts so the user only can see some columns by pages and reduce the load time, I think on pagination but the references only works for rows, How can I use it to separate the columns? It's that posible? I'ts a csv converted on a Dataframe with pandas

Comment: Pandas dataframe, does not have any built in capability to nor there is a full proof python library to do that. Best approach will be to mimic the pagination behaviour for your rows as in columns and slice first `n` rows from your dataframe and then show them incrementally

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that